# How can I add value in Django 2 template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

Scenario:I want to make a page for available slots for booking ,for which I want print time slot for 1 hour that is from i To i+1 and color it according to the availability.
I am newbie to django and can't figure out the way to make a calendar and that is why I am printing time values in HTML template.
Is there any other way to make this page and also is printing 'i+1' possible.

**Views.py**

```
@login_required
def slots(request):
    k={  'pro':range(8,17)
    }
    return render(request, 'login/slots.html',k)
```

**slots.html**

```
{% for i in pro %}
          <tr>  
           <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td id="demo">{{ i }} to {{ i+1 }}</td>
          </tr>
          {% endfor %}
```

I know this might be a silly question but I am not able to figure it out,
any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a built-in filter in Django template called `add`. You can add something to a value in templates using `{{ value|add:"2" }}`.

In this case specifically, try:

```
<td id="demo">{{ i }} to {{ i|add:"1" }}</td>
```

Comment: It worked !! I'll go through the documentation once again!! It would be nice if you give mre paticular link.

Comment: @Dev You can find more details here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/